# How to access a servlet variable inside javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet which has a variable which holds a JSON string.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("parameter", jsonList);
request.setAttribute("jsonstring", obj.toString());
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/file.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Now I am forwarding my request and response objects to a JSP page which contains a JS file.
How can I access the value of **jsonstring** variable inside the JS file.As I need to parse my JSON string further using jQuery.

I tried doing this in my JS file as I saw in some of the posts online.But it seems like its not working for me.

```
var test = '<%=request.getAttribute("jsonstring")%>'
```

Kindly guide me on the same.Thanx.

Answer (score 7):

If the JSP file uses a `<script>` tag to load an external JavaScript file, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/yourFile.js"></script>
```

then it won't work. What you have is a JSP scriptlet which only means something during the execution of the JSP file. That `yourFile.js` file won't be parsed server-side because it doesn't need to be. Only the browser will know what to do with the `<script>` tag and issue a request to the server to load the JavaScript.

In these cases what you can do is something like this inside your JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = <%=request.getAttribute("jsonstring")%>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/yourFile.js"/></script>
```

Since the JSP scriptlet is inside your JSP file it now actually gets processed correctly, and instead outputs the valid JSON for the object/array to store in the globally scoped `test` variable, which you can then refer to inside `yourFile.js`.

Comment: You're right, i have missed that he try to do that in a JS file :)

Comment: I'd suggest avoid using scriptlets. Use `${jsonstring}` rather

Comment: @Anthony..I was trying the same with external JS file from hours.Its working now.And thanks for such a nice explanation.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var test = <%=request.getAttribute("jsonstring")%>;
```

Else try that :

```
var test = eval('<%=request.getAttribute("jsonstring")%>');
```

Comment: can you provide the error? And can you provide the value of <%=request.getAttribute("jsonstring")%>?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value =<%=request.getAttribute("indicadorId") %>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

put object direct in the request like this

```
request.setAttribute("jsonstring", obj);
```

then assign request obj to js variable, it will be accessable as json object;

```
var test = <%=request.getAttribute("jsonstring")%>;
... = test.parameter;
```